# What files to copy from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 21.10 in order to make Bluetooth work properly?

Tags: bluetooth, 21.10

I have a dual boot of Ubuntu 20.04 and 21.10.
Bluetooth woks perfectly on 20.04 but in 21.10 I only have around 1 meter coverage, then I loose connection with the headphones I use.

What configuration should I look up and copy to get the same performance?

Comment: NONE. You do not copy files from one release to another.

Comment: Are your systems using the same kernel?  Ubuntu 20.04 LTS using the GA stack is using the 5.4 kernel, where as if using HWE & fully-upgraded it'll be using the stack that came from 21.10 (ie. 5.13 which is the kernel for 20.04.4 with HWE which has been rolling out to systems in recent weeks). You've provided no clue as to your issue; are your systems using the same kernel stack? or different stacks?  If the issue is different stacks; there is likely nothing you can do...

Comment: For 20.04 I am using 5.11.0-38-generic from LTS installation and for 21.10 I am using a ZEN SMP PREEMPT liquorix 5.16-8ubuntu1~impish, I got no clue for kernel stack

Comment: The first kernel you mention is EOL & *unsupported* (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS uses the 5.13 kernel & has now for weeks; systems using the GA kernels stack still on 5.4), the 21.10 kernel is 3rd party kernel & not a Ubuntu one.  Neither are *supported* Ubuntu kernels (the 5.11 one **was** but is no longer supported having been replaced)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.